# Issues in creation of new function on Cup-carbon

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I am trying to write my own function in Cup-carbon.

I followed the steps in the user-guide carefully, but an error appeared to tell me that **the variable Function_Calc can't be found**. The two codes I was added to the source-code are shown below.

I wrote the below code in this path.

(Path)  **Package** Script_functions=> **Class** ScriptFunction=> **method** 
 function

```
          if (function.equals("myf")){

                return Function_Calc.myf(args);

            }
```

I wrote the below code in this path.
(Path)  **Package** Script_functions=> **Class** Functions

```
public static String myf (String [] args) throws Exception{

                    String valToReturn = "Nassser";

                    return valToReturn;
```

}

And I invoked the function as follows:

```
function x myf
```

But unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Please try to make your code readable. Hint: There is ample help for formatting. Hint 2: Use at least four space to indent your code. Insert blank lines before and after code blocks.

Comment: I have been updated my question to be more readable. I hope it is easily readable now.